# Outlook Redemption not logging in on certain machines

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-redemption

Does anyone know why Redemption won't successfully logon?

What I'm doing is removing the default folders from a newly created PST. This is not an issue with any machines internally but on a clients machine, they get the following error.

Exception Source:      Redemption.RDOSession
Exception Type:        System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
Exception Message:     Not logged on. Please log on first
Exception Target Site: Logoff

```
public static void DeleteStoreFolders(string sStorePath)
        {
            RDOSession session = null;
            RDOPstStore RDOstore = null;
            try
            {
                _logger.LogDebug("init RDOSession");                
                session = RedemptionLoader.new_RDOSession();
                _logger.LogDebug("RDOSession created");
                _logger.LogDebug("Logging into store: " + sStorePath);
                RDOstore = session.LogonPstStore(sStorePath);
                _logger.LogDebug("Logged into store: " + sStorePath);
                foreach (RDOFolder folder in RDOstore.IPMRootFolder.Folders)
                {
                    _logger.LogDebug("Deleting folder " + folder);
                    folder.Delete();
                    _logger.LogDebug("Folder " + folder + " deleted");
                    if (folder != null)
                        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(folder);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError("Unable to delete default folders. " + ex.StackTrace);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (session != null)
                {
                    session.Logoff();
                    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(session);
                }
                if (RDOstore != null)
                    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(RDOstore);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please send a message to redemption (at) dimastr (dot) com, and I will send you the debug version of Redemption.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great to see the log generated on the problematic machine in addition to the exception details.

Also, I'd suggest replacing the `FinalReleaseComObject` methods with `ReleaseComObject` ones. The [Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.finalreleasecomobject?view=netcore-3.1) method releases all references to a Runtime Callable Wrapper (RCW) by setting its reference count to 0. That is not really a good idea. The [Marshal.ReleaseComObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject?view=netcore-3.1) method decrements the reference count of the Runtime Callable Wrapper (RCW) associated with the specified COM object. So, if you increase the reference counter, you need to decrease it accordingly, but not set it to zero!

Comment: are you looking for a specific log file?

Comment: what is the output on the problematic machine?

Comment: I have requested the logs from the user. It may take a whole day since they are on another continent.